# Python datetime.strptime not correctly parsing simple string

Tags: python

The string I want to parse is simply:

```
deadline = "Sunday 20 December, 2015"
```

I use:

```
datetime.datetime.strptime(deadline, "%A %j %B, %Y").date()
```

But for some reason it always parses as:

```
datetime.date(2015, 1, 20)
```

It's not correctly picking up the month. Any ideas?

Comment: I can't find a `%j` formatter in any documentation.

Comment: Rookie mistake. Thanks @mata. No idea how to select that as the correct answer.

Comment: @JoshLaird I've made it an answer instead of a comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`%j` is the day of the year, not the day of the month, use `%d` instead.